# creating new folder to store downloaded image

Tags: android, file

I was creating an app which download the image from the url then show that in a image view.
After that it checks that if there any folder on external sdcard with name **vedaImages** and if such folder exists then image is compressed and saved in it otherwise folder with that name is created and image is compressed and saved.

So upto showing it in ImageView is working well but folder are not been created.
here is the code of onrecieve method.

```
    private BroadcastReceiver downloadReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
        query.setFilterById(preferenceManager.getLong(strPref_Download_Id,
                0));
        Cursor cursor = downloadManager.query(query);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int columnIndex = cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
            int status = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
            if (status == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
                long downloadId = preferenceManager.getLong(
                        strPref_Download_Id, 0);
                ParcelFileDescriptor file;
                try {
                    file = downloadManager.openDownloadedFile(downloadId);
                    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseInputStream(
                            file);
                    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fileInputStream);
                    imgview.setImageBitmap(bm);

                    File f = new File(
                            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                    + "/vedaImages");

                    if (f.isDirectory()) {

                        File fileWithinMyDir = new File(f, "myfile");
                        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
                                fileWithinMyDir);
                        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, out);

                    } else {
                        File directory = new File(
                                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                        + File.separator + "vedaImages");
                        directory.mkdirs();

                        File fileWithinMyDir = new File(directory, "myfile");
                        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
                                fileWithinMyDir);
                        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, out);

                    }

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }

};
```

heres the logcat after pressing Download Button.

```
   07-05 02:40:34.646: D/GSMMUX(216): 3005:main(): Frames received/dropped: 55907/7
07-05 02:40:36.646: D/GSMMUX(216): 3005:main(): Frames received/dropped: 55909/7
07-05 02:40:37.726: D/AndroidRuntime(15857): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
07-05 02:40:37.726: D/AndroidRuntime(15857): CheckJNI is OFF
07-05 02:40:37.976: D/AndroidRuntime(15857): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
07-05 02:40:37.986: D/AndroidRuntime(15857): Shutting down VM
07-05 02:40:37.996: D/dalvikvm(15857): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
07-05 02:40:37.996: I/AndroidRuntime(15857): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
07-05 02:40:38.356: D/AndroidRuntime(15870): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
07-05 02:40:38.366: D/AndroidRuntime(15870): CheckJNI is OFF
07-05 02:40:38.616: D/AndroidRuntime(15870): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
07-05 02:40:38.626: I/ActivityManager(223): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.ved_download.download/.DownloadMainActivity} from pid 15870
07-05 02:40:38.706: D/AndroidRuntime(15870): Shutting down VM
07-05 02:40:38.726: D/ViewRootImpl(223): pckname = com.ved_download.download
07-05 02:40:38.726: D/dalvikvm(15870): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
07-05 02:40:38.736: I/AndroidRuntime(15870): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
07-05 02:40:38.786: D/OpenGLRenderer(402): Flushing caches (mode 1)
07-05 02:40:38.856: D/OpenGLRenderer(402): Flushing caches (mode 0)
07-05 02:40:38.956: D/ViewRootImpl(15434): pckname = com.ved_download.download
07-05 02:40:39.006: D/ViewRootImpl(15434): pckname = com.ved_download.download
07-05 02:40:39.226: I/Process(223): Sending signal. PID: 15434 SIG: 3
07-05 02:40:39.226: I/dalvikvm(15434): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-05 02:40:39.236: I/dalvikvm(15434): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-05 02:40:39.296: I/ActivityManager(223): Displayed com.ved_download.download/.DownloadMainActivity: +581ms
07-05 02:40:40.646: D/GSMMUX(216): 3005:main(): Frames received/dropped: 55929/7
07-05 02:40:45.406: I/DownloadManager(11827): Initiating request for download 87
07-05 02:40:45.486: D/ViewRootImpl(308): pckname = com.android.systemui
07-05 02:40:46.646: D/GSMMUX(216): 3005:main(): Frames received/dropped: 55948/7
07-05 02:40:48.646: D/GSMMUX(216): 3005:main(): Frames received/dropped: 55950/7
07-05 02:40:52.646: D/GSMMUX(216): 3005:main(): Frames received/dropped: 55953/7
07-05 02:40:54.646: D/GSMMUX(216): 3005:main(): Frames received/dropped: 55969/7
07-05 02:40:56.646: D/GSMMUX(216): 3005:main(): Frames received/dropped: 55971/7
07-05 02:41:00.646: D/GSMMUX(216): 3005:main(): Frames received/dropped: 55990/7
07-05 02:41:06.646: D/GSMMUX(216): 3005:main(): Frames received/dropped: 56011/7
07-05 02:41:09.036: I/qtaguid(11827): Failed write_ctrl(u 70) res=-1 errno=22
07-05 02:41:09.036: I/qtaguid(11827): Untagging socket 70 failed errno=-22
07-05 02:41:09.036: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(11827): untagSocket(70) failed with errno -22
07-05 02:41:09.416: W/CursorWrapperInner(15434): Cursor finalized without prior close()
07-05 02:41:09.536: W/System.err(15434): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/vedaImages/myfile: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
07-05 02:41:09.536: W/System.err(15434):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:406)
07-05 02:41:09.536: W/System.err(15434):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
07-05 02:41:09.536: W/System.err(15434):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
07-05 02:41:09.536: W/System.err(15434):    at com.ved_download.download.DownloadMainActivity$1.onReceive(DownloadMainActivity.java:110)
07-05 02:41:09.536: W/System.err(15434):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:728)
07-05 02:41:09.536: W/System.err(15434):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
07-05 02:41:09.536: W/System.err(15434):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-05 02:41:09.536: W/System.err(15434):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-05 02:41:09.536: W/System.err(15434):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-05 02:41:09.536: W/System.err(15434):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-05 02:41:09.536: W/System.err(15434):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-05 02:41:09.536: W/System.err(15434):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-05 02:41:09.546: W/System.err(15434):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-05 02:41:09.546: W/System.err(15434):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-05 02:41:09.546: W/System.err(15434): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
07-05 02:41:09.546: W/System.err(15434):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
07-05 02:41:09.546: W/System.err(15434):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
07-05 02:41:09.546: W/System.err(15434):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:390)
07-05 02:41:09.546: W/System.err(15434):    ... 13 more
07-05 02:41:12.646: D/GSMMUX(216): 3005:main(): Frames received/dropped: 56030/7
07-05 02:41:18.646: D/GSMMUX(216): 3005:main(): Frames received/dropped: 56051/7
07-05 02:41:24.646: D/GSMMUX(216): 3005:main(): Frames received/dropped: 56070/7
07-05 02:41:28.646: D/GSMMUX(216): 3005:main(): Frames received/dropped: 56072/7
07-05 02:41:30.646: D/GSMMUX(216): 3005:main(): Frames received/dropped: 56084/7
07-05 02:41:32.646: D/GSMMUX(216): 3005:main(): Frames received/dropped: 56115/7
```

Comment: What version of Android are you using? And do you have permission to write to the SD card?

Comment: minimum API is 8 and Target API is 19 ... yes i have added permission `uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"`

Comment: You have an exception? Post the logcat please. 19 is kitkat. If your devive is such that your dir is on removable media then your app has no write access. You can check with file.canWrite(). Try alternatively getExternalFilsDirs and getExternalFileDir.

Comment: hey i have posted the logcat ... yes there are some excption

Comment: Please remember that external storage of every phone is different, you can't hardcode it. getExternalStorageDirectory() could help you. In kitkat it's a bit hard to write everywhere in user sdcard.

Comment: Thanks @Marco Acierno .. but it will be very helpful if you could provide a small code snippet as i have tried this file writing for first time.

Comment: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/vedaImages/myfile: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory ......  at com.ved_download.download.DownloadMainActivity$1.onReceive(DownloadMainActivity.java:110)` dit you add mkdirs() and canWrite()?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to :

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/vedaImages/");

if(!file.exists()){
  file.mkdirs();
}
```

Also make sure that you have this permission :

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`